# Page Object Model for page with many elements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I'm currently working on a Selenium solution for my company's website. I'm trying to use the Page Object Model with Page Factories.  The difficulty that I'm encountering is with pages that have many elements on them.  I've seen in examples that it is good practice to create methods to encapsulate each action rather than just access the element directly (i.e. Create a method ClickButtonA() rather than using buttonA.click()

This?

```
public void login(String username, String password)
{
    usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
    passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
    loginButton.click();
}
```

Or something like

```
public void login(String username, String password)
{
    setUsername(username);
    setPassword(password);
    clickLogin();
}
```

My question is, what is best practice in this scenario?  Should I create methods to perform actions for each and every WebElement in the website or should I just create those on a need to use basis?

I feel like it is better practice to create those methods for every WebElement but  with 50+ elements, I feel like it ends up being a little bloated for redundant methods.

Comment: This is very opinionated. Personally I normally create a get and set for every element, as I create them. Then I create helper functions (like your login example) as needed.

Comment: Create a abstract pageobject in which u have methods like click(), sendkeys() etc which take in a webelement. Inherit from this pageobject and pass the webelement to get the desired action. Or even look at using a static method if u do not want to inherit. Cuts down on bloated code heavily but on the flip side the method name is generic and does not convey action clearly. Well as pointed above it is a choice.